# List of index out of range, I can't fix it

Tags: python

Can anyone help me with Python code?
I am trying to take all the data from a text file and save it as csv file.

The text file is like this :

```
DC Number: V70909
Name: A, SASHWIN
Race: ALL OTHERS/UNKNOWN
Sex: MALE
Birth Date: 04/27/1996
Custody: CLOSE
Release Date: 09/23/2021
Aliases:SASHWIN A, SASHWIN ASHOK, SASHWIN ASOKAN, A SASHWIN, ASOKAN SASHWINDC Number: 522180
Name: AALIM, MIKAIL N
Race: BLACK
Sex: MALE
Birth Date: 10/12/1950
Custody: COMMUNITY
Release Date: 08/05/2005
Aliases:MIKAIL AALIM, MIKAIL N AALIM, MIKAIL NAJI AALIM, LORENZO ANDERSON, LORENZO KENNETH ANDERSON, LEROY WILLIAMS ANGUS, ANGUS WILLIAMSDC Number: Y11193
Name: AALTO, MARK K
Race: WHITE
Sex: MALE
Birth Date: 06/29/1968
Custody: MEDIUM
Release Date: 05/31/2013
Aliases:MARK AALTO, MARK K AALTO, MARK KENNETH AALTODC Number: K87086
Name: AAMIR, OMAR T
Race: BLACK
Sex: MALE
Birth Date: 06/30/1992
Custody: MINIMUM
Release Date: 08/01/2019
Aliases:OMAR T AAMIR, OMAR TERRANCE AAMIR, KADEEM THOMPSONDC Number: 138198
Name: AANENSEN, JOHN A
```

The csv file i want it to look like is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DIGg.png)

This is my code

```
import csv
file_name = "readme.txt"
list_csv = []

# add header to csvlist_csv
header = ["DC Number", "Name", "Race", "Sex", "Birth Date", "Custody", "Release Date", "Aliases"]

# Write to csv file
# opening the csv file in 'a+' mode
csv_file_name = "my_csv.csv"
file = open(csv_file_name, 'w+', newline='\n')
write = csv.writer(file)
write.writerow(header)
# write.writerow(temp_list)

# headers
with open(file_name) as file_reader:
    lines = file_reader.readlines()

    for line in range(0, len(lines), 8):
        temp_list = []
        DC_Number = lines[line].split(":")[1].strip()
        name = lines[line + 1].split(":")[1].strip()
        race = lines[line + 2].split(":")[1].strip()
        sex = lines[line + 3].split(":")[1].strip()
        birth_date = lines[line + 4].split(":")[1].strip()
        custody = lines[line + 5].split(":")[1].strip()
        release_date = lines[line + 6].split(":")[1].strip()
        aliases = lines[line + 7].split(":")[1].strip()
        temp_list.append(DC_Number)
        temp_list.append(name)
        temp_list.append(race)
        temp_list.append(sex)
        temp_list.append(birth_date)
        temp_list.append(custody)
        temp_list.append(release_date)
        temp_list.append(aliases)
        # write content to csv

        write.writerow(temp_list)

file.close()  # close the file
```

Comment: Your question has severe formatting issues that make it hard to help you. Please see [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: are your total lines multiple of 8? for instance, for aliases why would it not go beyond the len(lines)?

Comment: btw, you are opening the file in w+ mode, not a+.

Comment: Your data seems to be broken. There are "DC Number:"s  at the end of Aliases lines.

Answer (score 0):

I see the core of the problem in following line

```
    for line in range(0, len(lines), 8):
```

You can't go with the line number up to `len(lines)` as you are using indexes above the line number to get next lines. You have to stop at the begin of the next 8 lines long section of the text file.

Notice that the data file example you provided starts with a header line and then the lines repeat each 7 lines. From this you have to read the header first and then go into the loop as follows:

```
    DC_Number = lines[0].split(":")[1].strip()
    for line in range(1, len(lines)-7, 7):
        name = lines[line + 0].split(":")[1].strip()
        race = lines[line + 1].split(":")[1].strip()
        ...
```

Below complete working code creating the desired result:

```
import csv
file_name = 'readme.txt'
# add header to csvlist_csv
header = ["Name", "Race", "Sex", "Birth Date", "Custody", "Release Date", "Aliases"]
# Write to csv file
# opening the csv file in 'a+' mode
csv_file_name = "my_csv.csv"
file = open(csv_file_name, 'w+', newline='\n')
write = csv.writer(file)
write.writerow(header)
with open(file_name) as file_reader:
    # lines = file_reader.readlines()
    lines = txtFile.split('\n')
    DC_Number = lines[0].split(":")[1].strip()
    # temp_list.append(DC_Number)
    for line in range(1, len(lines)-7, 7):
        temp_list  = []
        for colmn_no in range(0, 7):
            temp_list.append( lines[line + colmn_no].split(":")[1].strip() )
        # write content to csv
        write.writerow(temp_list)
```

Writes to the csv file:

```
Name,Race,Sex,Birth Date,Custody,Release Date,Aliases
"A, SASHWIN",ALL OTHERS/UNKNOWN,MALE,04/27/1996,CLOSE,09/23/2021,"SASHWIN A, SASHWIN ASHOK, SASHWIN ASOKAN, A SASHWIN, ASOKAN SASHWINDC Number"
"AALIM, MIKAIL N",BLACK,MALE,10/12/1950,COMMUNITY,08/05/2005,"MIKAIL AALIM, MIKAIL N AALIM, MIKAIL NAJI AALIM, LORENZO ANDERSON, LORENZO KENNETH ANDERSON, LEROY WILLIAMS ANGUS, ANGUS WILLIAMSDC Number"
"AALTO, MARK K",WHITE,MALE,06/29/1968,MEDIUM,05/31/2013,"MARK AALTO, MARK K AALTO, MARK KENNETH AALTODC Number"
"AAMIR, OMAR T",BLACK,MALE,06/30/1992,MINIMUM,08/01/2019,"OMAR T AAMIR, OMAR TERRANCE AAMIR, KADEEM THOMPSONDC Number"
```